# Cloud Run, Secret Manager and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I want to load whole .properties file from GCP Secret Manager to my Spring Boot application.

Secret is "mounted as volume" in Cloud Run (whole .properties file, in path `/secrets/secret.properties`), but I cannot manage to load it to Spring Boot using `spring.config.import`

I was trying:

```
spring.config.import=optional:configtree:/secrets/
spring.config.import=optional:classpath:/secrets/secret.properties
spring.config.import=optional:/secrets/secret.properties
```

but nothing works. Values are not visible in Spring Boot application.
(`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'x' in value "${x}"`)
When putting file on resource classpath, everything works.

Comment: Generally when "it does not work", there is an error report of some sorts.

Comment: can you share your Dockerfile, especially how you run your spring boot app at the end of the file?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere using jib tool with standard settings: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the set up that I have tested and which works (don't forget to grant the correct permissions)

JIB configuration

```
...
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <args>--spring.config.location=file:///secret/my.properties</args>
                    </container>
                    <to>
                        <image>gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/springboot</image>
                        <credHelper>gcr</credHelper>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
```

My Cloud Run deployment

```
gcloud beta run deploy --image=gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/springboot \
 --region=us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --platform=managed \
 --set-secrets=/secret/my.properties=projects/<PROJECT_Number>/secrets/springboot:1 \
secret-springboot
```